# Cannot read property 'join' of null error with node and GA analytics api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to use Google Analytics Core Reporting API from Node.js by following this tutorial http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/google-analytics-api.html. I'm launching the script directly from my terminal with `babel-node mygaapiscript.js`.  but I've got the following error :

```
  /Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/dashboard-ga/node_modules/gtoken/lib/index.js:160
        this.scope = options.scope.join(' ');
                                  ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null
        at GoogleToken._configure (/Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/dashboard-ga/node_modules/gtoken/lib/index.js:160:31)
        at new GoogleToken (/Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/dashboard-ga/node_modules/gtoken/lib/index.js:19:8)
        at JWT.GoogleToken [as gToken] (/Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/dashboard-ga/node_modules/gtoken/lib/index.js:17:12)
        at JWT._createGToken (/Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/dashboard-ga/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/jwtclient.js:218:24)
        at JWT.refreshToken_ (/Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/dashboard-ga/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/jwtclient.js:133:15)
        at JWT.authorize (/Users/me/Desktop/dashboard/me-MacBook-Pro:routes
```

What does this error mean ?

here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env babel-node
import google from 'googleapis';
'use strict';

import key from './client_id.json';
const VIEW_ID = 'ga:70810323';

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email, 
    key.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],null);

    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      let analytics = google.analytics('v3');
      queryData(analytics);
    });

    function queryData(analytics) {
      analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids': VIEW_ID,
        'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'max-results': 10,
      }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      });  
    }

module.exports = {queryData};
```

Got the `module.exports` because I'm using it inside express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments to `google.auth.JWT()` seem to be wrong. See the example in [the documentation](http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/12.4.0/index.html) and the JWT example in the `googleapis` repo [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/f8f59803860a6f69b2a7b23dcdf7994bc9079515/samples/jwt.js). The third argument should be the literal key data if you are not passing a key filename for the second argument. So just add `null` for the third argument:

```
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email, 
  key.private_key,
  null,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
  null
);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I did read the documentation and the JWT example but since It wasn't working, I guess I messed up the code a bit. However now I've got a brand new error `at Error (native)
  errno: -63,
  code: 'ENAMETOOLONG',
  syscall: 'open',` about my private key.

Comment: Does `key.private_key` contain the *actual* private key data or is it a filename? If it's actual key data, then you will need to swap the second and third arguments.

Comment: ok ok. I'm now understand the documentation. this point wasn't clear to me. I've got the following error `User does not have any Google Analytics account` so I guess it's working. Just need to play a bit with my GA account. thanks !